# What is better subquery vs literal on IN clause in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery, literals

Subquery on in clause:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE IN (SELECT Field1 FROM TABLE2)
```

Literal on in clause:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE IN (1,2,3,4)
```

Which query is better?

### Appends

Ok, let's I elaborate my database

```
-- `BOARD` is main board table
CREATE TABLE BOARD (
    BoardKey INT UNSIGNED,
    Content TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (BoardKey)
)

-- `VALUE` is extra value table  
CREATE TABLE VALUE (
    BoardKey INT UNSIGNED,
    Value TEXT
)
```

And this example is searching board record using EAV fields
First step is extract needed board keys from `VALUE` table
Next step is searching board from `BOARD` table using extracted board keys

> This example is just example,
>   so I don't need restructuring table design

Subquery on in clause:

```
SELECT * FROM BOARD WHERE (SELECT BoardKey FROM VALUE WHERE Value='SOME')
```

Literal on in clause:

```
SELECT BoardKey FROM VALUE WHERE AND Value='SOME'
```

> Get list of `BoardKey` and put to the some variable

```
SELECT * FROM BOARD WHERE BoardKey IN (1,2,3,4)
```

Comment: That does not make sense. If you don't need the subquery, use the numbers. Of course it is faster than select from another table.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your initial requirements. If you know the values (here 1,2,3,4) are static, you may hard code them. But if they will change in the future, it is better to use the sub query. Normally subquery is more durable but more resource consuming.

Please elaborate on your requirements, so that we can understand the problem and answer you better.

EDIT 1:

Ok, first of all, i have never seen a EAV model on two table, basically it is done with one table. In you case you will have difficulty searching for the key in the two table when you can combine them in one table. Ideally, you table should be like this :

```
CREATE TABLE BOARD
(
   BoardKey INT UNSIGNED,
   Content TEXT,
   Value TEXT
   PRIMARY KEY (BoardKey)
)
```

Finally, you can do

```
SELECT * FROM BOARD WHERE Value='SOME'
```

If the value 'SOME' will change in the future, better stick with Subquery. Hope it helped, vote answered if so.